# How to push a Borel measure down to the base of a covering.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose I have a covering space $E \rightarrow B$ and a Borel measure on $E$ such that each of the Deck transformations is measure preserving.  It seems like there should be a way to push the measure down to the base space, $B$.  Does anyone know the right way to think about and prove this?

Comment: Here's my intuition. Denote the measure on $E$ by $\mu$. I'd say an evenly covered neighbourhood $U$ has measure $\nu_0(U)=\mu(V_i)$ where $V_i$ is one of the sheets over $U$. Then I'd use $\nu_0$ to create an outer measure $\nu^*$. By the Carathéodory Theorem, the $\nu^*$-measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and $\nu := \nu^*|_{\mathcal{A}}$ is a complete measure. I have no idea if this works as there are several details I have not checked.

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelAlbanese .  This sounds like it probably works. Now I'm left wondering about what the appropriate uniqueness statement should be.

Comment: I'm guessing that if a measure $\lambda$ satisfies $\lambda(U) = \mu(V_i)$ for every evenly covered neighbourhood $U$, then $\lambda = \nu$, or something to that effect.